# Jquery width $(el).width() seems to fail here

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

http://jsfiddle.net/3BFGU/27/

Does anyone know why the width of the span containing text "ABC" is being returned 0.

1) Happens only in Firefox.
2) If i remove a span in between, it works ok. (http://jsfiddle.net/3BFGU/30/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why - it might be a bug; however, ...

Span's by default shouldn't have any width properties, of course they eventually do after the browser renders it.  What you could do is make them block-like elements, which should fix it:

```
span { display:inline-block; }
```

---

#### Edit:

Something else that's interesting is if you delete all the white-space between the ABC span and it's wrapper, it will work properly.  This might have something to do with the white-space and wrapping.  The browser might not be able to give a width because the container might start on one line and end on another.  That might explain why making it a block fixes it, since making the container a block, might keep the entire container together.

Comment: @sbr: updated the answer with some more explanation, which might help.  It's only conjecture from testing it a bit, so take it for what it is.

Comment: I also didn't mention that your `nowrap` css needs a period to work properly (`.nowrap`)

Comment: another interesting scenario, with FF only. http://jsfiddle.net/3BFGU/68/ . If I calculate individual widths of all spans, and add it, this comes out to be more than the total width of the outer div, if its width is set to "auto" .

Comment: For that scenario, I would use [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/); however the auto will be 1px bigger for some reason - oh I forgot, I think FF calculates widths as floats, so the decimal is probably getting dropped, which is affecting things.  I vaguely remember that I had to calculate the widths manually (getting margins, padding, and border with parseFloat)

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/3BFGU/74/ -- note: getComputedStyle, is different for IE, which uses something like `currentStyle`, you would have to put your own logic in to really get something cross-browser.  To help understand, if computed style is `auto`, parseFloat will return `NaN`, so in those cases, I specified to use jQuery's default `width()` function.  Also, I forgot to add in the border widths.

Comment: Not sure if you should use Math.floor here, but the numbers will equal if you drop the fraction of a pixel: http://jsfiddle.net/3BFGU/87/  (again this is not a cross-browser solution as it stands because it uses getComputedStyle)